# Can I still use PNG with multiple densities?

Tags: android, android-studio, png

I already made icons, backgrounds etc of the app as PNG but later found out that it is now advisable to use Vectors using the studio with SVG files. I can't recreate the designs in SVG as it is tedious. PNG to SVG converters just loses it major parts of those designs.

Can I still keep using PNG with multiple densities from Kitkat to the latest versions?

Comment: What happens if you try? I suspect your application will run as usual, but possibly with less sharp images. If so, it's your decision whether that's okay-ish or not.

Comment: Yes. You can still use PNG images.